# Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: 'component' is not a known element despite already generated using angular cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Error shown when I inspected the page:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'registration' is not a known element:
1. If 'registration' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
```

At first, I generated 'name' component using angular cli:

```
ng g c name
```

It was successfully generated and registered to `app-module.ts`:

```
PS C:\Users\prtkh\Desktop\hello-world> ng g c name
CREATE src/app/name/name.component.html (31 bytes)
CREATE src/app/name/name.component.spec.ts (670 bytes)
CREATE src/app/name/name.component.ts (293 bytes)
CREATE src/app/name/name.component.css (0 bytes)
UPDATE src/app/name.module.ts (654 bytes)
```

I checked name.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-registration',
  templateUrl: './name.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./name.component.css']
})
export class NameComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

And name.component.spec.ts:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { NameComponent } from './name.component';

describe('NameComponent', () => {
  let component: NameComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<NameComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ NameComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NameComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Noticed that my **angular's version** is **6.0.7** and **angular-cli's** is **6.0.8**.

In my **app-component.html**

```
     <h1>Angular</h1>
   <name></name>
```

In my **app-module.ts**, the `name` component is in `declaration` and `export`:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NameComponent } from './name/name.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NameComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    NameComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { 

}
```

I am beginner to Angular, so I thought problem would not happen because I used shorthand command in `Angular-CLI` to generate all boilerplate code for a component.

Comment: your name component selector is app-registration and you used <name></name> instead.

Comment: In your `app.component.html` instead of `<name></name>` try `<app-registration></app-registration>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution for this in your app-component.html. you have to access following way

Your html code part wrong,   `<name></name>`

Change like this,

```
<app-registration></app-registration>
```

Thats all. Its solve your problem.

Let try this once and let me know.

Comment: Why iam get downvote. Down voter must tell reason first.

Comment: Yes, sir @Karnan Muthukumar. It works. The fact I use 'name' just to represent a common name of a component. The mistake I made that in `app-component.html` I wrote `<registration></registration>` instead of `<app-registration></registration>`.

Comment: pls feel free to mark as answer. First answer said only me

Answer (score 0):

You should use Your app selector in your html code which is **app-registration**

So it's tag is

```html
<app-registration></app-registration>.
```

you should change

```html
   <name></name>
```

To

```html
<app-registration></app-registration>.
```